# How can I write a method within a Django model to retrieve related objects?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, frameworks

I have two models. We'll call them object A and object B. Their design looks something like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()

class Bar(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField()
     Foo= models.ForeignKey('myapp.Foo')
```

Now, suppose I want to make a method within Foo that returns all Bar objects that reference that instance of Foo. How do I do this?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()
     def returnBars(self):
         ????
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get this for free:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

By default, you can access a Manager which gives you access to related items through a `RELATEDCLASSNAME_set` attribute:

```
some_foo.bar_set.all()
```

Or you can use the `related_name` argument to `ForeignKey` to specify the attribute which should hold the reverse relationship Manager:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()

class Bar(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField()
     foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars')

...

some_foo.bars.all()
```